# Try to achieve EXIST in Linq, but Any() in where clause for Nested Query takes forever to process

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am trying to use Any() in where clause but it takes forever to run. The data itself is about 1 million rows. I had working version on SQL but for some reason I have to run it on linq in C#. The SQL version works really fast which takes about 8 seconds to process but I am not sure if linq is something different.

There are two important parameters called ClientNum and CreateDate. The ClientNum can have duplicated records.

The hard part is I have to get distinct client number which it has only one record in 365 days, so the code is actually calling it self in where clause.

This is the SQL code:

```
select distinct(t1.ClientNum), month(t1.CreateDate) as monthnum from table1 t1
where 
t1.CreateDate >= '2017-01-15' and 
t1.CreateDate <= '2017-09-17' and
exists
(
  select ClientNum, CreateDate from table1 t2
  where
  t2.ClientNum = t1.ClientNum and
  (
    (t2.CreateDate < t1.CreateDate and
        t2.CreateDate > DATEADD(YEAR,-1,t1.CreateDate))
    or
    (t1.CreateDate < t2.CreateDate and
        t1.CreateDate > DATEADD(YEAR,-1,t2.CreateDate))
  )
)
```

I think linq should always work pretty same speed as SQL.

When I try to use the code below in C#, the code was taking forever to process.

```
db.table1
            .Where(o =>
                    o.CreateDate >= new Datetime(2017,1,15)
                && o.CreateDate <= new Datetime(2017,9,17)
                && db.table1.Any(x =>
                       x.ClientNum == o.ClientNum
                   && (
                           (x.CreateDate < o.CreateDate && x.CreateDate > o.CreateDate.Value.AddYears(-1))
                           || (o.CreateDate < x.CreateDate && o.CreateDate > x.CreateDate.Value.AddYears(-1))
                       ))
            ).ToList();
```

Not sure if its the problem of too much data in that table.

Can anyone help me a little why it is stucked at the Any() function? Or if there is any other way to achieve the "exists" function similar to SQL?

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Can you explain, in English, what your query does/is meant to do?

Comment: suggest split to smaller pieces of linq, test, if work then try to combine a larger one.

Comment: o.CreateDate >= new Datetime()
=> why did you create DateTime for this case? Please send us the real LINQ statement that you wrote.

Comment: @huile sorry I forgot to update it. it should be a specific datetime which passed in to this query. I have edit the question

Comment: @spender The query was try to filter a table, which find out the uniq ClientNum that the record has been created only once in one year period. For example the ClientNum can be appeared in the table couple times with different create date since the create date is for the row not the Client Num. Then I need to find out if during 2017/1/15 to 2017/9/17, any Client Num only appears one time.

Comment: @LeiYang actually I tried.. it just stops at the Any() part. so that I was thinking about if it is caused by the large amount of data

Comment: @kim, I didn't understand why you have to use '"exists'" in SQL. I thought it's nonsense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think your SQL should be:**

```
SELECT t1.ClientNum, MAX(MONTH(t1.CreateDate)) AS monthnum FROM table1 t1
JOIN  table1 t2 ON t2.ClientNum = t1.ClientNum
WHERE  
t1.CreateDate >= '2017-01-15' AND 
t1.CreateDate <= '2017-09-17' AND
(t2.CreateDate < t1.CreateDate AND
    t2.CreateDate > DATEADD(YEAR,-1,t1.CreateDate))
OR
(t1.CreateDate < t2.CreateDate AND
    t1.CreateDate > DATEADD(YEAR,-1,t2.CreateDate))
)
GROUP BY t1.ClientNum
HAVING COUNT(t2.ClientNum) = 1
```

**Then, your LINQ statment will be:**

```
List<Table1> Table1 = new List<Table1>();

var query1 = from t1 in Table1
             join t2 in Table1 on t1.ClientNum equals t2.ClientNum
             where t1.CreateDate >= new DateTime(2017, 1, 15) && t1.CreateDate <= new DateTime(2017, 9, 17)
                 && ((t2.CreateDate < t1.CreateDate && t2.CreateDate > t1.CreateDate.AddYears(-1))
                 || (t1.CreateDate < t2.CreateDate && t1.CreateDate > t2.CreateDate.AddYears(-1)))
             select new { t1, t2 };

//Check either it run forerver or not 
var result1 = query1.ToList();

//Check either it run forerver or not 
var result = query1.GroupBy(p => p.t1.ClientNum)
  .Where(p => p.Count() == 1)
  .Select(p => new { ClientNum = p.Key, monthnum = p.Max(a => a.t1.CreateDate).Month })
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @hiule Actually I use "exist" in SQL is because I only need to know if this record exists. In stead of join, "exists" runs faster in SQL. But it is really hard to do the same logic on linq. Your code gives perfect idea for me how to make it work on linq and helped me find out the problems in my c# code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you're running in SQL, the data doesn't travel on the wire - it's all in memory/disk which is much faster than pushing million rows over the wire.  That said, that's probably not what accounts for the slowdown.

If you were to run the SQL query and take a look at the execution plan used, the `EXISTS` portion is likely rewritten as a JOIN, or at least as read a dataset into hashset and then probe into the hashset for matches.  Read table once is a million reads, but once converted into hashset, probe into hashset should be O(1) operation. (And possibly other optimizations based on indices which we cannot see from your example for lack of schema.)  So it's basically O(2N) = O(N), i.e. linear operation.

With LINQ, as written, you're basically having it go row by row into `.Where`, and then `.Any` scans the same source again.  So it is O(N^2), a.k.a. quadratic performance, which for size of million is a lot.

I see couple of possible approaches.  One is to first read through table and build a dictionary with appropriate key using LINQ's `.ToDictionary`, and then inside `.Where` probe into that dictionary, making performance linear.

Alternatively, you can perform a join which essentially would do the same thing under the hood.

Lastly, your LINQ logic around date comparison doesn't seem to be the same as SQL.  I'll use SQL as the source of truth in reworking the logic.

```
db.table1
    .Join(db.table1, a => a.ClientNum, b => b.ClientNum, (a, b) => new { T1 = a, T2 = b })
     .Where(o =>
                (o.T2.CreateDate < o.T1.CreateDate
                && o.T2.CreateDate > o.T1.CreateDate.AddYear(-1))
                ||
                (o.T1.CreateDate < o.T2.CreateDate
                && o.T1.CreateDate > o.T2.CreateDate.AddYear(-1))
        ).ToList();
```

Note that for this to work, contents of `db.tabld1` should be re-enumerable.  that is you can get a new instance of `IEnumerable<T>` from it, such as an array or list.  If consuming data once causes data to become volatile, you would first need to build data into memory using something like `.ToArray` assigning result to variable, and then doing join off of that variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer.@LB2 Although the code is still one step away but the theory you mentioned is very very useful for me. I didn't realize EXISTS works likely as Join so the time complexity is way better than .Any in Linq. This explains why it takes like forever when I apply it in linq with Any

Comment: @kim You're welcome. The part that works like JOIN is not so much EXISTS as it is equating column from inner table query with a column in the outer table query.